# Counting presence of discount ranges in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a simple orders table for a product being sold that has a column with the discount per order.  For example:

```
Order Number   DiscountPrcnt
1234           0
1235           10
1236           41
```

What I would like to do is create an output where I can join the order table to a customer table and group the discounts into ranges by email, as follows:

```
Email_Address   0-20  20-50  50-100
joe@abc.com           Yes    Yes
tom@abc.com     Yes   Yes
```

So the idea is to determine if each customer (here designated by email) has ever received a discount in the specified range, and if not, it should return NULL for the range.

A simplified version of the table structure is:

```
Customer Table:

CustID   Email
123      joe@abc.com
234      tom@abc.com
456      joe@abc.com
```

So emails can repeat across customers.

```
Orders Table:
CustID   OrderID   Amount   DiscPrcnt
123      1234      50.00    0
234      1235      75.00    10
456      1236      20.00    41
```

Comment: show the customer table and order table structure

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.email, COUNT(o1.order_number),  COUNT(o2.order_number),  COUNT(o3.order_number)
from customer c, order o1, order o2, order o3
where c.CustID = o1.CustId
and c.CustID = o2.CustID
and c.CustID = o3.CustID
and o1.DiscountPrcnt > 0
and o1.DiscountPrcnt <= 20
and o2.DiscountPrcnt > 2
and o2.DiscountPrcnt <= 50
and o3.DiscountPrcnt > 50
and o3.DiscountPrcnt <= 100
group by c.email
```

You'll not get yes as expected but the number of time the user benefits the discount. 0 if none.

Comment: Is it possible to take a different approach and have all the code within the select statement for each column? Because I will have many other columns in the final output besides the discount buckets. Perhaps using a case statement but I don't understand that well enough